# R data.table fwrite irregularity

Tags: excel, csv

I'm attempting to write below dataframe to a csv and excel file.

```
df = data.frame(a = 1:4,b = c("TRUE","FALSE","true","false"))    
data.table::fwrite(df,"test_csv.csv",quote = T)  
openxlsx::write.xlsx(df,"test_excel.xlsx")
```

Upon opening the files in Microsoft Excel, I observe that case in 2nd column has automatically changed in CSV file(while data in .xlsx file is in order). Why does it happen and how do I avoid CSV file data get erroneously changed?

Please refer to below screenshot for more clarity
[image]

Comment: Investigate content of file to see if problem is in openxlsx or data.table and rework your questions. It is now confusing. It is not difficult to just preview flat file. `cat test_csv.csv` gives `"TRUE","FALSE","true","false"` as expected. As of now it looks like excel has problem to properly read a csv file, if so we can safely remove `data.table` tag from that question.

Comment: Open with a text editor and see that the file was properly written. And LibreOffice shows the same. This seems to be exclusively an Excel issue.